# Question about closed paths in the fundamental group of a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> If $f$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$ and if $m \in \Bbb Z$, then $t \rightarrow f(t)^m$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$ and $\deg f^m = m \deg f$

It's easy to see that they are both closed paths in $S^1$ at $1$ since they're essentially elements of $\{ z \in \Bbb C : |z| = 1\}$, but I'm having trouble showing the second part.

I can show by induction and by constructing a homotopy that $\deg f^m = m \deg f$, for $m \in \Bbb Z^+$ through use of the fact that $d : \pi_1(S^1, 1) \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ is an isomorphism with $[f] \rightarrow \deg f = f'(1)$, where $f'(1)$ is the lifting of $f$ into $(\Bbb R, t_0)$ where $t_0$ is an integer.

But I'm confused as to how I'd show this for $m=0$ or $m \in \Bbb Z^-$.

Is there any easier way to prove this, or does anyone have any idea how to show their equality with negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a lift of $f$ through the universal cover $p\colon t\mapsto e^{2i\pi t}$, then notice that $m\theta$ is a lift of $f^m$. Indeed, notice that:
$$f^m(t)=\left(e^{2i\pi\theta(t)}\right)^m=e^{2i\pi m\theta(t)}.$$
Therefore, $\deg(f^m)=m\theta(1)-m\theta(0)=m(\theta(1)-\theta(0))=m\deg(f)$.

Comment: The book I'm reading hasn't talked about universal covers yet.  Is there a way to show this without using them?

Comment: You don't really need to know that $p$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{S}^1$, just that for all $f\in C^0(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathbb{S}^1)$, there exists $\theta\in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that: $$f=p\circ\theta.$$
Which is certainly done in your book, since you know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1,\cdot)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What does the notation $C^0(\Bbb S^1, \Bbb S^1)$ mean?

Comment: It is the set of continuous function from $\mathbb{S}^1$ with values in $\mathbb{S}^1$, this is the set of closed loops of $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: How does $\deg (f^m) = m \theta(1) - m \theta(0)$?  The only definition of $\deg g$ I'm aware of is $g'(1)$, where $g '$ is the lift of $g$.  I understand how you get the $m \theta(1)$, but no the $m \theta(0)$.

Comment: What is your definition of a lift? Mine is a $\theta$ such that $f=e^{2i\pi\theta}$, then the degree is defined to be: $$\theta(1)-\theta(0).$$
I am pretty sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: This is the definition given in Rotman's Algebraic Topology:  A lifting of a function $f : (I, \{0,1\}) \rightarrow (\Bbb S^1, 1)$ is defined as a continuous function $f ' : (X, x_0)  \rightarrow (\Bbb R,t_0)$, where $t_0 \in \Bbb Z$, such that $\exp f ' = f$.  All of the $(A,B)$ are pointed sets $A$ with basepoint $B$.

Comment: We are talking about the same thing except that I do not fix an origin for my lifts, namely I do not ask for $f'(x_0)=t_0$ instead of I am subtracting the initial value of my lift, hence the $-m\theta(0)$ that surprised you earlier. Honestly, this is the first time I see this definition, which book are you using?

Comment: Thank you, I understand how your proof applies to the definition I was using.  And the book is Algebraic Topology by Rotman.