# If $f$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$, then $\deg (f^m) = m \deg(f)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups

> If $f$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$ and if $m \in \Bbb Z$, then $\deg (f^m) = m \deg (f)$

The proof is the answer of the question
[Question about closed paths in the fundamental group of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291012/question-about-closed-paths-in-the-fundamental-group-of-a-circle)

I rewrite it and I also have a question on why  $\deg(f^m)=m\theta(1)=m\deg(f)$.

**Proof.**

Consider the following commutative diagram

\begin{array}{ccccccccc} (\mathbb R,\{0,1\}) &   \\
\uparrow{\theta} & \searrow{\exp} &  \\
(I,\{0,1\}) & \xrightarrow{f} & (S^1,1) &  
\end{array}

We have $\exp\circ\theta=f$

and $\exp\circ\theta^m=f^m$

and $\deg (f^m)=\deg(e^{2m\pi i\theta})=m\theta(1)=m\deg(f)$

Can anyone explain why $\deg(e^{2m\pi i\theta})=m\theta(1)$?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding some of your notation. What is this map $\theta: (I,\{0,1\}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\{0,1\})$? Is it definitely a map which is sending $\{0,1\} \subseteq I$ to $\{0,1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$? Does $\theta^m$ mean $m \theta$?

Comment: @Matt To calculate the lift of $f$, $f$ must be defined as $f:(I,I^\circ)\to(S^1,1)$  (by definition). As $I^\circ=\{0,1\}$, I wrote $f:(I,\{0,1\})\to(S^1,1)$ and $\theta:(I,\{0,1\})\to(\mathbb R,\{0,1\}).$ I was not sure about the codomain $(\mathbb R,\{0,1\})$, it could be $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ so I wrote both $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: It is supposed to choose only one (0 or 1) and then send it under $\theta$.Even tho you write both $\{0,1\}\mapsto\{0,1\}$ under $\theta$

Comment: And no, $\theta^m\neq m\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\theta : (I,\{0,1\}) \to (\mathbb R,\{0,1\})$ is not correct because it suggests $\theta(\{0,1\})  \subset \{0,1\}$. In fact, $\theta$ is the unique lift of $f$ (lift means $\exp \circ \theta = f$) such that $\theta(0) = 0$. Since $e^{2\pi i \theta(1)} = exp(\theta(1)) = f(1) = 1$, we see that $\theta(1) \in \mathbb Z$. The number $\theta(1)$ is the degree of $f$.

We have $f^m(z) = (f(z))^m$. What is the lift of this map? It is $m\theta$ which is defined as $(m\theta)(t) = m \cdot \theta(t)$. In fact we have $(m\theta)(0) = 0$ and $$exp((m\theta)(t)) = exp(m\theta(t)) = e^{2 \pi i m \theta(t)} = e^{m \cdot 2 \pi i \theta(t)} = (e^{2 \pi i \theta(t)})^m = exp(\theta(t))^m = f^m(t) .$$
This shows $\deg (f^m) = (m\theta)(1) = m \theta(1) = m\deg(f)$.